# $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du$, which of the following option is true?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an increasing real valued function on $[0,\infty)$ with $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ and let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du$; $0 < x <\infty$, Then which of the following are true:

$1)$ $g(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$

$2)$ $xg(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$

$3)$ $g(x)\geq f(0)$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$

$4)$ $yg(y)-xg(x)\leq (y-x)f(y)$ for all $x<y$

How can I approach this ? I need some hints.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) is obviously true. Use the fact that $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Do not use derivatives. You can answer this question using just the definition of an increasing function. For example $0 ,y <x$ implies $f(y) \leq f(x)$. Can you prove 1) from this?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I can not see it. Let me spend more time on this. sorry

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Done!!! Thanks

Comment: If $0<u<x$ then $f(u) \leq f(x)$. Integrate both sides from $0$ to $x$. When you integrate $f(x)$ with respect to $u$ the variable $x$ acts as a constant, so $\int_0^{x}f(x)du=f(x)\int_0^{x}du=f(x)x$. Hence $\int_0^{x}f(u)du \leq xf(x)$.  Dividing by $x$ we get $g(x) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$. If you understand this part you will be able to handle the other parts also.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Your hint was great. I solved in the exact same way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) is false: take $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. The other three are all true and they follow by monotonicity. [For 4) note that $\int_x^{y} f(t) dt \leq \int_x^{y} f(y) dt=(y-x)f(y)$].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint for (at least) 1) and 3):
$$
\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(u)\,du
$$
is the mean value of $f$ over the interval $[0,x]$. I think this is the type of question where giving away too much will just spoil it all. Thus, I stop with this hint (as you asked for) for now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$g(x)=\frac{\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du}{\int_{0}^{x}du}$

This is related to average. It can be managed from here